# Расчет расстояния из широты и долготы

Tags: android, java

У меня возникла вот такая проблема, при расчете расстояния между двумя точками на карте обновление данных идет не каждые там 1 километр хотя бы, а каждые 50 - 90 км. Рассчитываю вот так:

```
public void getDistanceMeters() {

    Location locationA = new Location("point A");
    locationA.setLatitude(lat);
    locationA.setLongitude(lng);
    Location locationB = new Location("point B");
    locationB.setLatitude(lat2);
    locationB.setLongitude(lng2);
    int currentDistance = (int) locationA.distanceTo(locationB) / 1000;
    totalDistance += Math.abs(distance - currentDistance);
    distance = currentDistance;
}
```

Может тут нужно что то изменить что бы обновлялось чаще?

Comment: Прошу прощения, а почему тип (int)? Он разве не отбрасывает дробную часть?

Comment: а мне не нужна дробная часть

Comment: А, ну тогда вопросов нет. (плюс-минус километр)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В этом методе Вы наврядли что-то сможете ускорить, попробуйте объявить несколько провайдеров для определения местоположения (и Internet и GPS, можно еще и пассивный)

Еще совет: метод **distanceTo()** дает неверную дистанцию (недавно столкнулся с такой же задачей, не сходились данные, полученные с iPhone, с моими. Я ради интереса посмотрел на картах гугла и яндекса, выяснилось что разница в 10 км)

Используйте вот эту формулу:

```
double lon, lat, lon2, lat2;    
double result = 111.2 * Math.sqrt( (lon - lon2)*(lon - lon2) + (lat - lat2)*Math.cos(Math.PI*lon/180)*(lat - lat2)*Math.cos(Math.PI*lon/180));
```

Comment: попробую спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Есть два более математических варианта. Извиняюсь что на языке Dart, но плюс минус этот вариант будет на всех языках одинаковым. Итак, есть два метода, попроще и посложнее. Не буду расписывать математически что тут происходит, можете почитать более детально по ссылкам на википедию.
В примере оба варианта будут возвращать дистанцию в **метрах**

Первый метод: Haversine algorithm (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula)

Его точность около 0.3%, но он работает быстро.

```dart
/// Equator radius in meter (WGS84 ellipsoid)
const double equatorRadius = 6378137.0;

double distance(final LatLng p1, final LatLng p2) {
    final sinDLat = math.sin((p2.latitudeInRad - p1.latitudeInRad) / 2);
    final sinDLng = math.sin((p2.longitudeInRad - p1.longitudeInRad) / 2);

    // Sides
    final a = sinDLat * sinDLat +
        sinDLng *
            sinDLng *
            math.cos(p1.latitudeInRad) *
            math.cos(p2.latitudeInRad);
    final c = 2 * math.atan2(math.sqrt(a), math.sqrt(1 - a));

    return equatorRadius * c;
}
```

Второй вариант Vincenty algorithm (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vincenty%27s_formulae).

Его точность 0.5 миллиметра, но он гараздо сложнее и трудозатратнее для процессора.

```dart
/// Equator radius in meter (WGS84 ellipsoid)
const double equatorRadius = 6378137.0;

/// Polar radius in meter (WGS84 ellipsoid)
const double polarRadius = 6356752.314245;

/// WGS84
const double flattening = 1 / 298.257223563;

/// Earth radius in meter
const double earthRadius = equatorRadius;

/// The PI constant.
const double pi = math.pi;

double distance(final LatLng p1, final LatLng p2) {
    var a = equatorRadius,
        b = polarRadius,
        f = flattening; // WGS-84 ellipsoid params

    var l = p2.longitudeInRad - p1.longitudeInRad;
    var u1 = math.atan((1 - f) * math.tan(p1.latitudeInRad));
    var u2 = math.atan((1 - f) * math.tan(p2.latitudeInRad));
    var sinU1 = math.sin(u1), cosU1 = math.cos(u1);
    var sinU2 = math.sin(u2), cosU2 = math.cos(u2);

    double sinLambda,
        cosLambda,
        sinSigma,
        cosSigma,
        sigma,
        sinAlpha,
        cosSqAlpha,
        cos2SigmaM;
    double lambda = l, lambdaP;
    var maxIterations = 200;

    do {
      sinLambda = math.sin(lambda);
      cosLambda = math.cos(lambda);
      sinSigma = math.sqrt((cosU2 * sinLambda) * (cosU2 * sinLambda) +
          (cosU1 * sinU2 - sinU1 * cosU2 * cosLambda) *
              (cosU1 * sinU2 - sinU1 * cosU2 * cosLambda));

      if (sinSigma == 0) {
        return 0.0; // co-incident points
      }

      cosSigma = sinU1 * sinU2 + cosU1 * cosU2 * cosLambda;
      sigma = math.atan2(sinSigma, cosSigma);
      sinAlpha = cosU1 * cosU2 * sinLambda / sinSigma;
      cosSqAlpha = 1 - sinAlpha * sinAlpha;
      cos2SigmaM = cosSigma - 2 * sinU1 * sinU2 / cosSqAlpha;

      if (cos2SigmaM.isNaN) {
        cos2SigmaM = 0.0; // equatorial line: cosSqAlpha=0 (§6)
      }

      var C = f / 16 * cosSqAlpha * (4 + f * (4 - 3 * cosSqAlpha));
      lambdaP = lambda;
      lambda = l +
          (1 - C) *
              f *
              sinAlpha *
              (sigma +
                  C *
                      sinSigma *
                      (cos2SigmaM +
                          C * cosSigma * (-1 + 2 * cos2SigmaM * cos2SigmaM)));
    } while ((lambda - lambdaP).abs() > 1e-12 && --maxIterations > 0);

    if (maxIterations == 0) {
      throw StateError('Distance calculation faild to converge!');
    }

    var uSq = cosSqAlpha * (a * a - b * b) / (b * b);
    var A = 1 + uSq / 16384 * (4096 + uSq * (-768 + uSq * (320 - 175 * uSq)));
    var B = uSq / 1024 * (256 + uSq * (-128 + uSq * (74 - 47 * uSq)));
    var deltaSigma = B *
        sinSigma *
        (cos2SigmaM +
            B /
                4 *
                (cosSigma * (-1 + 2 * cos2SigmaM * cos2SigmaM) -
                    B /
                        6 *
                        cos2SigmaM *
                        (-3 + 4 * sinSigma * sinSigma) *
                        (-3 + 4 * cos2SigmaM * cos2SigmaM)));

    var dist = b * A * (sigma - deltaSigma);

    return dist;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
double result = Math.sqrt(Math.pow((111321 * cos(Math.toRadians(lat)) * (lon)) - (111321 * cos(Math.toRadians(lat)) * (lo3)), 2)
                        + Math.pow(111111 * (lat) - 111111 * (la3), 2));
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: а la3 и lo3 это что у вас и откуда вы их взяли?